# npm install is not working / takes a long time in some networks

Tags: node.js, npm

If I ran command `npm install` while I am in my home wi-fi network, it takes a long time to complete, and sometimes if I try to do a clean install after deleting `node_modules`, it may not complete at all.

But, if I use USB tethered network from my android phone instead of the wi-fi network, `npm install` works fine.

My wi-fi network is not particularly slow. It is a fiber connection.

This issue didn't appear today itself. I had been experiencing this for quite a some time now.

What could be the reason behind this? Any ideas for troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: Hi there, have you managed to sort it out? Facing the same thing and I'm wondering what could be the cause.

Comment: @el.severo No, I couldn't find a solution. I just switch the network when it's not working and then it works.